# Howto make a very specific table

Tags: tables

[image]

I wanna make something like the table in the picture.So far i only managed to do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTleft{-110pt} 
\setlength\LTright{\fill}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lllll}

\caption{Quick guide to GPU terms}\\
\hline
\bfseries Type &\bfseries Descriptive name &\bfseries Closest Term &\bfseries Official term &\bfseries Definition\\ \hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endlastfoot
\hline
Program abstractions       &Vectorizable Loop         &Vectorizable Loop       &Grid     &Vectorizable Loop       \\        \hline
(put in this space the above title vertically)   &some     &some       &some      &some                                   \\       \hline
(same as above)                                        &some     &some       &some      &some                                   \\       \hline

Machine object          &Thread SIMD               & Thread Vector            &  Warp    &      SIMD Processor\\ \hline
(put in this space the above title vertically)&some     & some                         &  some      &   some\\                  \hline
(same as above)&some                          & some                         &  some      &   some\\                  \hline

Processing Hardware &some                          & some                         &  some      &   some\\                  \hline
(put in this space the above title vertically)&some                          & some            &  some      &   some\\              \hline
(same as above)&some                          & some                         &  some      &   some\\                  \hline

Memory Hardware     &some                          & some                         &  some      &   some\\                  \hline
(put in this space the above title vertically)&some   & some                         &  some      &   some\\               \hline
(same as above)&some                          & some                         &  some      &   some\\                  \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone point how to do this?

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid vertical text as much as possible. There's no point in doing it for such a table; just separate the big chunks with horizontal rules, but don't use rules in the chunks corresponding to a given type.

Setting the type slightly offset and in a different font will help readers in understanding its role.

I use a single `tabular`, rather than `longtable`, adapt it to your needs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Quick guide to GPU terms}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
&\bfseries Descriptive name &\bfseries Closest Term &
  \bfseries Official term &\bfseries Definition\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Program abstractions} \\
&Vectorizable Loop & Vectorizable Loop & Grid & Vectorizable Loop \\
&some              & some              & some & some              \\
&some              & some              & some & some              \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Machine object} \\
&Thread SIMD       & Thread Vector     & Warp & SIMD Processor\\ 
&some              & some              & some & some              \\
&some              & some              & some & some              \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Processing Hardware} \\
&some              & some              & some & some              \\
&some              & some              & some & some              \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{5}{@{}l}{\itshape Memory Hardware} \\
&some              & some              & some & some              \\
&some              & some              & some & some              \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]